# Oracle data modeler: How Create prodcedure and function

Tags: oracle

How create procedure e.g.:

```
    Create PROCEDURE il_klub as (
      select
        sum(krk.kluby_id),
        r.nazwa
      FROM
        rozgrywki_klubowe r,
        kluby_roz_klub krk
      WHERE
        r.id = krk.rozgrywki_klubowe_id
      GROUP by r.nazwa
      )
```

and function e.g.:

```
DECLARE @mistrz TABLE (nazwa varchar, rozgrywki varchar)
INSER INTO @mistrz (nazwa, rozgrywki)
select
k.nazwa, r.nazwa
from
kluby k,
rozgrywki_klubowe r,
kluby_roz_klub krk,
historia_roz_klub hrk,
where
k.id = krk.kluby_id and k.id = hrk.kluby_id and r.id = krk.rozgrywki_klubowe_id 
  and r.id = hrk.rozgrywki_klubowe_id 
  and hrk.miejsce =1 and r.system like 'ligowy'

Select * from @mistrz
```

In Oracle SQL Data Modeler

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a procedure declaration is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE IL_KLUB AS
  vSUM_KLUBY  KLUBY_ROZ_KLUB%TYPE;
  vNAZWA      ROZGRYWKI_KNUBOWE.NAZWA%TYPE;
BEGIN
  select sum(krk.kluby_id),
         r.nazwa
    INTO vSUM_KLUBY,
         vNAZWA
    FROM rozgrywki_klubowe r,
         kluby_roz_klub krk
    WHERE r.id = krk.rozgrywki_klubowe_id
    GROUP by r.nazwa;
END IL_KLUB;
```

This procedure is, obviously, not particularly useful as it doesn't do anything with the results of the SELECT, and that will probably draw a compilation warning. But that's how you declare it.

A function is defined in similar fashion, but you also need to define a return type, and then return a value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IL_KLUB_NAZWA
  RETURN ROZGRYWKI_KNUBOWE.NAZWA%TYPE
AS
  vSUM_KLUBY  KLUBY_ROZ_KLUB%TYPE;
  vNAZWA      ROZGRYWKI_KNUBOWE.NAZWA%TYPE;
BEGIN
  select sum(krk.kluby_id),
         r.nazwa
    INTO vSUM_KLUBY,
         vNAZWA
    FROM rozgrywki_klubowe r,
         kluby_roz_klub krk
    WHERE r.id = krk.rozgrywki_klubowe_id
    GROUP by r.nazwa;

  RETURN vNAZWA;
END IL_KLUB_NAZWA;
```

[Oracle PL/SQL Language Reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/toc.htm)

[Oracle SQL Language Reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm)

Best of luck.